# Move folders or files one directory up from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am looking to move all files in one specific directory up one directory with the terminal. There are hidden files and that is why I want to use the terminal. Looking for something like:

```js
mv ./ to ../
```

Not certain on the above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

`mv my_folder ../my_folder`

Comment: That is what I am looking for! Perfect Thank you. I thought it would keep everything in the package but it spread the files. Thanks

Comment: `mv my_folder ../my_folder`  without the leading slash on the first argument as that is an absolute path.

Comment: @RichardBarber I agree. The accepted answer should be edited.

Comment: 3 years later, what if I am in the folder and want the contents of the folder to move up one level?  The answer given just put the folder up one level but I want the contents so they line up next to the folder itself.